# Apache redirect for the page ends with .html and leave the page as it is if any query string followed the same page

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two page urls:

> 1. www.example.com/indexsearch.html
> 2. www.example.com/indexsearch.html?q=dell

I like to redirect the pages that ends with .html(1) only to

> www.example.com/

so I have written the redirect rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^/site-search.html$ / [R=301,L]
```

This one **also affects the second(2) url**, because of this redirect rule, the url is changing to

> www.example.com/?q=dell

I need the url to be the same www.example.com/indexsearch.html?q=dell. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect `/site-search.html` to `homepage` when there is no querystring, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site-search\.html\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

This does not affect the uri `/site-search.html?querystring`

You can also match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable using a `RewriteCond`  check if it is empty then redirect the request

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/site-search\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, stakeen. this one worked as expected, also i want to know one more detail from this, is that possible to use one RewriteCond to more than 10 RewriteRules ?, I mean that same RewriteCond  for next 10 different *.search.html pages

Comment: No, thats not possible. You can use multiple RewriteConds for a single rule. But you can not use multiple rules under 1 condition on mod-rewrite. see the official mod-rewrite documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i will go with the single condition